# does $w_1^{n-1}$ denote whole the sentence in the context of word prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language

this [NLP book](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/3.pdf) gives

> When we use a bigram model to predict the conditional probability of
>   the next word, we are thus making the following approximation:

$P(w_n|w_1^{n-1}) \approx P(w_n|w_{n-1})$

does $w_1^{n-1}$ denote whole the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page 3, the notation is defined:

> We'll represent a sequence of $N$ words either as $w_1 \ldots w_n$ or $w_1^n$ (so the expression $w_1^{n-1}$ means the string $w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_{n−1}$).

So yes, it represents the sequence of words from $w_1$ to $w_{n-1}$, i.e. the whole sentence up to that point.

Comment: However, in the special case where the sequence $w_i$ is a Markov chain, then knowing $w_{n-1}$ is the same as knowing $w_1^{n-1}.$

Comment: Thanks for you answer. $w_1^n$. Here has nothing to do with exponential computation, right?

Comment: Nothing at all, they're just using the superscript to differentiate the two symbols.